# Are there any factors that affect how fast a pokemon gains experience on Isle Evelup?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

There are several features in Pokemon Sun and Pokemon Moon that give your pokemon additional experience after every battle. The ones that I know about are:

- Trade Bonus - Pokemon caught or hatched by another trainer and traded to your game gain 50% more experience than pokemon you caught or hatched yourself.
- Refresh Bonus - If your pokemon has two or more hearts in Pokemon Refresh (called Pokémon Amie in Generation 6 games), it will gain 20% more experience.
- Lucky Egg bonus - The held item Lucky Egg (which you can get by speaking to Kukui after getting 50 entries in your pokedex or by stealing from wild Chansey) will increase the experience the pokemon holding it receives by 50%

Do any of these have an affect on how much experience a pokemon gains using the Level Boost drink in Poke Pelago?

Comment: I would also be interested to know if I can boost the rate at which pokemon gain EVs or hatch in Pelago. Should I edit my question, or ask separate ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect of the drinks increase with Isle Evelup's level. All the following values are per session.

Drink -- Level 1 -- Level 2 -- Level 3

Level Boost -- 100 exp -- 200 exp -- 300 exp
HP Boost -- 1 EV -- 2 EV -- 4EV
Attack Boost -- 1 EV -- 2 EV -- 4EV
Defence Boost -- 1 EV -- 2 EV -- 4EV
Sp. Attack Boost -- 1 EV -- 2 EV -- 4EV
Sp. Defence Boost -- 1 EV -- 2 EV -- 4EV
Speed Boost -- 1 EV -- 2 EV -- 4EV

However, I'm not sure how the other exp effects work in conjunction with Level Boost. So this only answers the base part of your question and the question in your comments.

Comment: Hmm...this base information is useful, but I was looking for any buffs on top of this base "per-session" yield. I don't have access to Pokerus or the power band/similar items, but I may run some experiments myself and post an answer of my own.

Answer (score 2):

So I've done my own test on this, and none of the boosts I was interested in - different trainer, Refresh, and Lucky Egg - had any effect. I had four level 1 Littens - one obtained through Wonder Trading, one who had more than 2 heart in Pokemon Refresh, one who was holding a Lucky Egg, and one I used as a control. After subjecting all four Littens to 40+ hours with the Level Up drink, none of the Littens had gained any more experience than the other. All of them were the same level, and even had the same "XP to next level" number. If you want more experience, it looks like you either have to let your pokemon play for more sessions, or just grind for experience the old fashion way.